# Combining multiple MySQL subqueries into one

Tags: mysql

I have a query that contains that contains three sub queries:

```
select 
    *,
    (select count(*) from v2_page_views left join v2_pages on v2_page_views.pageID=v2_pages.pageID where v2_page_views.siteID=1 and userID=v2_users.userID and pageTemperature=0) cold, 
    (select count(*) from v2_page_views left join v2_pages on v2_page_views.pageID=v2_pages.pageID where v2_page_views.siteID=1 and userID=v2_users.userID and pageTemperature=1) warm, 
    (select count(*) from v2_page_views left join v2_pages on v2_page_views.pageID=v2_pages.pageID where v2_page_views.siteID=1 and userID=v2_users.userID and pageTemperature=2) hot 
from v2_page_views 
left join v2_users on v2_page_views.userID=v2_users.userID
```

I am trying to improve the speed and it seems like combining the three sub queries into one would be a good idea.

My issue is that I am unsure whether it's even possible to output multiple values from a single sub query ... and how I would go about writing a single query. I suspect it will involve `IF`, `CASE` and `WHEN` but I am unsure ...

Comment: Please post a `SHOW CREATE TABLE` statement and some sample data, this will enable us to help you

Comment: I do not believe you need any sub-queries. Just a single JOIN with conditional aggregation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
select v2_page_views.columnThatIsId
       sum(case when pageTemperature=0 then 1 else 0 end) cold,
       sum(case when pageTemperature=1 then 1 else 0 end) warm,
       sum(case when pageTemperature=2 then 1 else 0 end) hot
  from v2_page_views 
        left join v2_users 
          on v2_page_views.userID=v2_users.userID
 where v2_page_views.siteID=1
 group by v2_page_views.columnThatIsId
```

If you need other columns just join this with the table you need. Be aware to maintain the group by intact to not generate wrong values.

To this specific solution I gave you wont even need the left join because there is nothing from that table. This is just a heads up. If you are still unable to figure out the whole solution let me know, I will edit with it.